# EPPlus: formula that references other Worksheet

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, epplus

I need the formula

```
='C:\awp\API\dde\awp.xla'!blp(A" + i + ";$B$1)
```

and have tried it this way:

```
ws.Cells[i, 2].Formula = @"'C:\awp\API\dde\awp.xla'!blp(A" + i + ";$B$1)";
```

Result is "unreadable content": a broken formula that is removed by excel.

**How can I reference a cell in another Worksheet in EPPlus?** Thank you for input!

Comment: When, as said here: https://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/393112 , I open the file as zip and check for how the formula is internally saved, the formula is displayed as [1]!blp(A4,$B$3) ..

Comment: Hm alright, figured out the link to an external file is somewhat splitted into a reference to an external sheet and the file. The info is stored in several externalLink1.xml / externalLink1.xml.rels files and [1] in previous comment seems to be itself a reference to that. :o/